# C#: WebClient - Cant Unrecognize cyrillic characters

Tags: c#, webclient, encode, windows-1251

Trying to parse site: [link](https://spravnik.com/rossiya/novosibirskaya-oblast/oblastnoj-tsyentr/novosibirsk?serchStreet=12%20%E4%E5%EA%E0%E1%F0%FF%20%F3%EB.)

Code to download content:

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
client.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII; // OR UTF8
string reply = client.DownloadString(url);
```

Response:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#">
<head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1251">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/vnd.microsoft.icon" href="https://spravnik.com/favicon.ico"/>
    <link rel="SHORTCUT ICON" href="https://spravnik.com/favicon.ico"/>
    <link href="/src/main.css?v=1.25" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="https://cdn.contentsitesrv.com/js/push/subscribe.js?v=1.3.0"></script>
<title>??????????? 12 ??????? ??. - ?????????? ?????????? ??????</title>
<meta name="keywords" content="?????????? ?????????? ????????????, ???? 09 ????????????, ?????????? ????? ????????????"/>
<meta name="description" content="? ??????????? &#9742; ????????? ?? ??????? ????? ??? ???? ???????????? ?? 12 ??????? ??. ????? ???????? ?? ?????? ????????, ?????? ???????? ????? ???????? ? ????? ?? ?????? ????????."/>
<meta property="og:title" content="?????????? ??????????. ??????????? ? ?? ??????...!"/>
```

All cyrillic characters are converted in "???" Or in ����

Comment: What happens if you use UTF-8? And what about Windows-1251, since that seems to be what the server prefers?

Comment: Use UTF-8 (not ascii which will corrupt the data).  The viewer you are using is ascii and will not show the characters properly but the file downloaded correctly.  You need to view the data with a viewer that uses cryillic charater font.

Comment: ASCII - ??? symbols
UTF-8 - ��� symbols

Windows-1251 not provided in prompt list:
https://ibb.co/Lkhz0w1

Comment: @jdweng https://ibb.co/6Rfs1HX

Comment: See http://www.liangshunet.com/en/202003/567276536.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this site just ignores your Client Encoding and return you data in 1251 encoding. I prefer using RestClient and check responses ContentType. But if you absolutely sure about this site - the code below works correctly.

```
WebClient client = new WebClient {Encoding = Encoding.UTF8};
byte[] reply = client.DownloadData(url);

Encoding.RegisterProvider(CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance);
Encoding encoding1251 = Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1251");
var convertedBytes = Encoding.Convert(encoding1251, Encoding.UTF8, reply);

string result = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(convertedBytes);
```